# Splunk Subsearch, Using value from field in primary search used to conduct a secondary search

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

I need to pull information from two indices, I need to use a username from a search in my first index to then search in a second index to pull that user's corresponding email address from a different field. I have been trying different way with "search" and then with "join" but whatever im doing just isnt working.

`index=dlp sourcetype="security:ta" signature="Administrative account was enabled"`
`| rename file_name as username`
`| join type=left username [search index=aad_enterprise userDisplayName=username | fields userPrincipalName | format | table userPrincipalName ]`
`| table _time user userPrincipalName`

The above is using the value of "username"  from my first search and being used to match the "userDisplayName" field in the second search being done in the "aad_enterprise" index. I want to be able to use the value from the "userPrincipalName" field from the second search in my main one, because this is the user's email and I need it to be tabled out with more information being pulled out in my first search.

Is what im trying to do possible? Thank you in advance

Here are some queries I have tried with no success:

`index=dlp sourcetype="security:ta" signature="Administrative account was enabled"`
`| rename file_name as username`
`| join type=left username [search index=aad_enterprise userDisplayName=username | fields userPrincipalName | format | table userPrincipalName ]`
`| table _time user userPrincipalName`

and

`index=dlp sourcetype="security:ta" signature="Administrative account was enabled"`
 `[search index=aad`*`enterprise userDisplayName=username`*`| fields userPrincipalName | rename userPrincipalName as userEmail]`
`| table _time username userPrincipalName`

Comment: The output table should have the following fields : unsername (use `|rename userDisplayName AS username`) as well as all other fields you want to join into your main/first search.

Comment: The searches on either side of the `join` command are independent.  Neither knows anything about the results of the other and there is no way to pass values from one to the other.  There may be other ways to accomplish this, but first tell us what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Im trying to pull a username and their correspondening email. The issue is the security alerts that I have in the index=dlp only contains the username "LastName, First", but I also need the user's email which is located in the second index=aad_enterprise. 

So I wanted to take the username that is generated in the security logs in index=dlp and use that to search the index=aad_enterprise to find the corresponding email address.

I then wanted to use that email as a field in my main query regarding index=dlp. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The first query should work with a little modification.  Don't bother trying to match userDisplayName to username - `join` will do that.

```
index=dlp sourcetype="security:ta" signature="Administrative account was enabled" 
| rename file_name as username 
| join type=left username [search index=aad_enterprise 
  | fields userPrincipalName 
  | rename userPrincipalName as username
  | format ] 
| table _time username
```

Be advised the `join` command is not very performant.